# SVN: Maintaining a trunk and a single bugfix branch

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

I'll describe the scenario I'm trying to achieve. I'm interested in whether this is possible using Subversion:

1. I'm working on an application which is released to the public.
2. It is being built using a Jenkins CI server and automatically uploaded to the Web server for download.
3. I keep the major development work on the **trunk**. Major releases come from the trunk, but they are not very often (2-3 per month).
4. After a release, I want to be able to quickly fix any bugs, so I have a **bugfixing branch** which is branched from the latest major release. Here the hot fixes can be solved and released fairly quickly (within a day).
5. After each major release, I want that bugfixing branch to somehow be rebased to the trunk. In other words, I don't want to constantly create new release branches, for practicality reasons: CI server keeps the same SVN URL, no need for large checkouts etc.

**Questions**:

1. Is the rebasing possible without the need to merge from the trunk to the bugfix branch after each release? I'm worried about various tree conflicts since I do a lot of refactoring of the code.
2. Is it simple to do?
3. Are there any alternative strategies? I know I can switch the logic and keep the main development work on a branch, but I want to avoid this because most of the code changes happen on trunk and this requires less merging effort.
4. Is Mercurial a better option for such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

what you do is a valid approach, you're problem is merging changes back onto trunk.. then just merge them.

Firstly, when you release, create a branch at that point - this is your code for the released version. You can bugfix directly onto it if you like, which sounds like the way you'd be best off working. When you make a bugfix there, just merge the change directly to the trunk. You don't need to rebase (or reintegrate) or anything, just take the revisions that changed and merge them onto trunk almost as they are made. This is very simple - you're doing the simplest merge SVN provides (merging a range of revisions), just pick the revisions that contain changes you want and merge them onto trunk.

You may run into conflicts in this case, but remember that svn performs merging by diffing the source changes and applying them to the target. If you move half the code out of a file into another and then try to merge using any tool, you'll have difficulties.

Mercurial might be better at this - I'd recommend trying it, create a repo, add some files, branch, seriously refactor your files, then make a small change and merge it back. see if you end up with similar problems that you'd get with SVN (as you're trying to do a lot of work, and I don't think any computer will be too good at such extensive changes).

Of course the better answer is to stop doing so much refactoring your code looks like a different product!

Comment: Refactoring = changing the code while the functionality remains the same.Also, you haven't really answered my question: what happens when the _second_ release is out? A new branch? Or having to merge all the changes from the trunk back to the bugfixing branch? I want to avoid either, and that was the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found at least part of the answer in this SO answer: [What are you supposed to do with old SVN branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899956/what-are-you-supposed-to-do-with-old-svn-branches/2900233#2900233)

So basically, I could delete the bugfixing branch after each release and then create a new one with the same name. Whether this is a good practice, I don't know.